# Do we need to formally teach the Greek Alphabet?

Tags: soft-question, education

This is a question that I am purely interested in because I think we never thought about this before in Mathematics education... or even so was not discussed.

When did we learn the Greek alphabets when we learnt mathematics? For example, I was pretty afraid when I saw $\text{Pressure} = h\rho g$ or even the idea where the variable for an angle was $\theta$ and that was when I was in 8th grade.

When I went to high school, I got even more confused when I saw letters like $\mu, \lambda, \sigma$ during statistics class. During calculus class, don't we remember the $\delta$ represnting small changes and our peers write it like a small d? Even only when I was in *4th year of* college that I realize $\Sigma$ represents sum because Sigma and Sum start with 'S' and $\Pi$ represents produce because Pi and Product start with 'P' (it's for my memory but I'm not sure if it was taught this way.

So the question is: do we need to formally teach the Greek alphabet (not all but slowly) and tell them that researchers use these letters frequently to represent certain variables before we teach them? Of course, as student of math, we hardly (if ever) say $X$ follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $m$ or other correct, but "weird" sounding statements. I remember doing it during high school statistics... because I strongly believe that these "seemingly scary" letters "turn off" math students in the pre-college level.

Comment: No I don't think so. They closely resemble English lettering so they're more or less recognizable. They are just characters after all. We use tons of characters in daily life. The seldom appearance of Greek letters do not turn students off from mathematics. There are many other reasons they are turned off from mathematics (inability to handle abstraction, terrible instruction, lack of general intrigue). This is very much a non-issue as far as I am concerned.

Comment: For what it's worth, in the U.S. a lot of college students (and even high school students) are familar with capital Greek letters from their use in the names of fraternities and sororities.

Comment: When I was almost done with my math degree, I realized I knew ~75% of the greek alphabet, so I just taught myself the rest.

Comment: @CameronWilliams That doesn't strike you as a rather dangerous assumption with nothing to back it up?

Comment: Also, do you seriously think that, say, `psi` is "more or less recognizable"? Or, worse, `xi` (especially the way I usually see math teachers draw it, which is as a couple of curly scribbles)?

Comment: Be wary of responses from too many mathematically successful students here. The Greek alphabet is alien to very many North American students, and just that unfamiliarity can indeed be an obstacle between the students and paying attention to the important math concept. I wouldn't go so far as to formally teach the Greek alphabet, but I do try to stress they they are just letters like our regular Latin letters. I even throw up some words in Greek sometimes and try to get students to pronounce them: $\mu\alpha\theta\eta\mu\alpha\tau\iota\kappa\alpha$, $\pi{o}\lambda\upsilon\gamma\omega\nu$, etc.

Comment: Perhaps school geometry should be taught from Euclid's *Elements* [in the original language](http://www.claymath.org/euclid/index/book-1-definitions) with a translation for those who are beginners

Comment: Regarding $\sum$ and $\prod$, apparently $\sum$ was introduced by Euler (writing in Latin: summa) and $\prod$ either by Descartes (writing in French: produit) or Gauss (writing in Latin: productus), so they don't *quite* stand for "sum" and "product". (Source: http://jeff560.tripod.com/operation.html)

Comment: What I personally think would have been useful is some instruction in how to physically form the glyphs on paper by hand, since it was sometimes not totally obvious from the typed glyph how to do this. I personally have always had extremely good mathematical handwriting (I have a minor calligraphy hobby), but many of my peers seemed to have struggled with this sort of thing until I showed them how I stroke the glyphs, typically out of frustration with being unable to understand theirs.

Comment: @AJMansfield: Yes, a short course on Greek handwriting would be nice, especially if it could be made mandatory for would-be lecturers. ;-) It ought to help reduce the sightings of the dreaded Unidentified Greek Letter (is it a $\xi$? is it a $\zeta$? maybe it's an $\varepsilon$?) on blackboards...

Comment: On the bright side, the Greek alphabet is about 7.5% shorter than the English one!

Comment: What about just mentioning on every new introduced letter "this is µ and it is the Greek equivalent of m". That should be enough, or, at least, better than nothing.

Comment: As a Greek I must say, learning the language well is hard, like most languages, but learning just the alphabet is not this hard. e.g. like people in material arts learning random Korean and Japanese words.

Comment: I learned to read the New Testament in Greek just from my math classes. Not a joke.

Comment: I never really considered this a problem, and I _still_ don't know most of the Greek alphabet. They're just symbols representing functions or variables. They might as well be flibble and thunk as opposed to alpha and theta, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Learning the greek alphabet was the exercise #0 on the first exercise list for the introduction to mathematics course I was taking. No one really did it, but by the end of the first year, after being taught some elementary set theory (basic ordinal&cardinal arithmetic, Konig's lemma and the sort), where then-funky symbols like $\lambda,\kappa,\zeta,\xi$ cropped up a lot, I just decided to learn all of the greek alphabet in sequence. Two years later, I was surprised that no one, not even the professors, recognized the letter $\upsilon$ (upsilon), not even by name. :)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I _am_ Greek and can assure you that Greek math teachers also have issues writing legible characters. And this in the alphabet we consider normal. I think it's like MDs, there is a sort of glamour where the worse the handwriting, the better the mathematician (or doctor).

Comment: Note also that $\sum$ doesn't "start with" an S, it *is* an S. Similarly for $\prod$.

Comment: More than one undergrad at Oxford referred to xi and zeta as "squiggle" and "other squiggle". I don't know for sure, but maybe *realising that it makes no difference to the answer if you do call them that* is in itself a significant insight for kids :-) The practical question, then, is how to coach them towards realising (a) why a symbol is just an arbitrary symbol and then (b) in which case why the heck not just pick a Latin character and random, why choose one over another and why include Greek?

Comment: one of my profs sometimes used "squiggle" to keep us on our toes. (he called it that and it was just a squiggle, not a greek letter of any kind)

Comment: The Greek alphabet started getting useful when I was 14 years old, for my geometry lessons at school. Kept being useful since then.
But I had a Greek alphabet table lying around in my dictionary, so it wasn't that hard to find (no Internet then).

Comment: Everything that went up is TL;DR for me, but I was just going to say "No, there is enough formal teaching of sundry details distracting students as it is. Taking time to emphasize such things is not a good use of time. There is plenty of opportunity to learn a Greek letter or two or ten just as you need them."

Answer (score 47):

I teach physics. When a Greek letter comes up for the first time in my course, I try to make sure that it's explicitly described for them, either in lecture or in the text. They need to know that it's a Greek letter, what it's called, how to write it, and what sound it makes in Greek. They don't know these things without being told. In particular, they often see a letter like $\rho$ and just assume it's some kind of stylized letter "p." Likewise for $\gamma$ as "y," $\nu$ as "v." Teaching the whole alphabet all at once wouldn't work; they wouldn't retain it because they wouldn't be using it. It's unfortunate that the LaTeX $\gamma$ looks a lot like a "y," and someone looking at it can't tell that there's supposed to be a loop at the bottom.

You could say that students should just look these things up if they don't know them. There are two problems with this approach: (1) if they think $\rho$ is just a stylized "p," then they don't know that it's Greek and they need to look it up; (2) if you expect them to look it up, they won't, and then you'll have to grit your teeth every time you grade their paper and seem then writing $\gamma$ as "y."

Comment: As an additional comment: Where can I look up "γ"? It's not really searchable with google, most math books have no useful dictionary or lookup table and even asking your teacher is difficult if you have no idea how that thing is pronounced.

Comment: @ChristianSauer: If you already know it's a Greek letter, it's not hard to Google for it (or just look it up in a book, for the more old-fashioned folks). If you have no idea *what* that squiggle is, then you may be out of luck unless you can, say, bring the book with you and show it to your teacher.

Comment: @ChristianSauer Would it be cheating to use http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html?

Comment: γ is a Greek letter called "gamma": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma

Comment: @ChristianSauer if you have any greek letter or may of the more common unicode symbols for maths, paste them into wikipedia's search box - it might be only the start of your search, but it's quite reliable.

Comment: @ChrisH True, and very useful when reading from a digital source. (The Google search bar also accepts unicode and similar.) But what about when you're reading from a book? What about when you're watching a lecture?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni That's pretty awesome. I think there's a somewhat similar Microsoft Windows built-in application that could help, too.

Comment: Yeah, it's a pet peeve of mine that people use $\rho$ as if it was a $p$ in a funny font. Likewise, $\nu$ is not a funny $v$ and $\eta$ is not a funny $n$.

Comment: also, "$\omega$" as "w".

Comment: Do you know a reference where I can hear "what sound it makes in greek"?

Comment: @ChrisH Awesome sugestion. I never tried that - so it it's a great improvement. But I think the problem still persists because it don't really work in a classroom :(

Comment: @DavidRicherby: On the other hand, using $\nu$ as a funny $n$ is technically valid. ;-) But yes, that particular confusion is very common. I just attended a seminar a few days ago where the presenter used $\eta$ on the blackboard and kept calling it "nu" until someone in the audience spoke up.

Comment: Just for completeness: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%CE%B3

Answer (score 43):

Many successful (ex-)students seem to assume "this was no problem for me, so I assume it will be no problem for other students." (For examples of this attitude, see some of the early comments on the question, some of the now-low-voted answers, and even one of the comments on this answer.) This is not just a bad assumption; from a teaching perspective, it's possibly the *worst* assumption one can make. (Full disclosure: I didn't find this a problem either, but I've always been fairly good at math. However, I know a *lot* of people who have been turned off to math precisely for reasons like this that seem trivial to those (like myself) who don't happen to find them off-putting.)

Personally, I think there's legitimate reason for concern here, but "formally teaching" the entire alphabet probably isn't going to solve the root problem, or at least, it isn't going to be the most efficient or effective way to solve it. If you teach the alphabet all in one go as an alphabet, you're just giving students a whole bunch of random symbols to memorize all at once instead of giving them a couple of random symbols at a time with no context.

So I would suggest instead that for the first couple times each non-Latin symbol is used, the teacher should (1) mention what alphabet it's from, (2) say the symbol's name and, if there's a Latin equivalent, what the equivalent is, (3) state whether the symbol is an arbitrary choice for the example at hand (such as using `epsilon` rather than `x` as the argument of a trig function) or a standard convention that the students should memorize (such as using capital `pi` for a product), and (4) if applicable, whether the choice of characters has anything to do with their usage (as in the case of `Pi` for product, with the aforementioned "p is for product" connection).

EDIT: Even for students who (1) don't find unexplained mysterious symbols off-putting and (2) are good at looking things up outside of class, teachers can unintentionally conceal some genuine and important subtleties. For instance, it wasn't until my third or fourth year of taking classes involving calculus that I realized [there's a distinction between the `d` symbol used for single-dimension derivation and the `partial` symbol used in multiple dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/317345/52057).

EDIT 2: removed reference to "most of the answers so far," which is now fortunately long-obsolete.

Comment: A great answer.
I was one of those students you did mention. I was quite afraid of formulars. When I finally learned the meaning of the letters, it was much easier to understand the formula. It was no longer a wall of meaningless gibberish (like a unknown arabic writing still is) but something where I could other formulas / values in, and achieve something.

Comment: @kyle Nice icon :) (Recognize mine?)

Comment: @rschwieb Ha! Thanks. Yes indeed, I do. Miss that comic...

Comment: Sad we keep dumbing down our kids and underestimating their capacity to learn just for the sake of it. I memorized the entire Greek alphabet before I was ten, simply because we had a cool dictionary that had a bunch of alphabets and I thought it was fun. That helped me tremendously and I believe we can do the same for our kids today.

Comment: @JimiOke "We can do the same" meaning we can ensure that every kid has a "cool dictionary with a bunch of alphabets" in their house, which we assume that they will find and read?

Answer (score 10):

As a below average mathematician I was grateful for the teachers who explained symbols to us.
The Greek alphabet might be a special case - but I think not.
As a student, you don't know what the "funny symbols" are, what their name and spelling is and so you have difficulty to put a name on a concept.
Suppose somebody teaches you a simple concept, draws a unknown symbol next to it and goes to the next concept - because there is no familiar name for the symbol, you will probably forget it and have trouble when you need it.
I failed quite miserably at math at one time and was quite afraid of Greek symbols until a teacher sat down and explained to me their drawing, their spelling and what concept is behind each symbol.

As an analogy: Many programming languages have dictionaries, where you can access some value by a key. But you are out of luck when you don't know the key. The Greek alphabet is similar: Sure, the concepts are more important, but it helps when the name / spelling of each Greek letter is readily available in the student's memory.

Comment: You're not really “out of luck” if you don't know the key; you can just do a linear search through the dictionary's values until you find what you're looking for.  Of course, this takes O(n) rather than O(1) time.

Comment: @Dan I know, but I cannot do that with my brain ;)

Answer (score 5):

I think we should. The reason is that there is a correspondence between Greek letters and Roman letters, which is often kept too implicit to those that do not know the actual alphabet. $\Pi$ doesn't represent the product because "pi" begins with a "p". $\Pi$ represents the product because $\Pi$ *is* a "P", in Greek.

Therefore, I think every mathematics or physics student should know the whole Greek alphabet, what sounds the letters make, and what Roman letters they correspond to (there is not an exact 1-1 mapping here: for example the vowels E and H are both roughly "E", and the letter $\Psi$ has no direct Roman equivalent). Just knowing the very basics of the alphabet is very illuminating. For example, why do we use $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ for angles? (Answer: because they are the first three letters of the Greek alphabet)

It's also important to know both uppercase and lowercase letters. That way, we are not so confused when $\Sigma$ and $\sigma$ correspond to roughly the same thing, and we know how to make the same correspondence with any letter, just as we should not be confused about why either is used in place of $S$ or $s$.

Comment: I think it's equally important to demonstrate how to *write* the letters, particularly the ones that confuse students: $\varphi, \vartheta, \xi, \zeta$. Even handing out a chart like http://www.covingtoninnovations.com/pens/GreekChartLarge.jpg can be helpful. Unfortunately, many students I encounter are not very culturally sensitive, and think that e.g. "$\xi$" is a joke rather than an actual letter.

Comment: I really hate $\xi$. I have bad handwriting, and have always just written it as a scribble. I have no way of distinguishing it from $\zeta$ in my writing. But maybe you are right that if I had been taught how to actually write the letter formally it would be better.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't go so far as to try to distinguish $\phi$ from $\varphi$ and $\theta$ from $\vartheta$. In courses I would always write them in one way regardless of how the professor wrote them.

Comment: FWIW, as a student I distinguished xi from zeta by writing xi with almost straight lines, basically a horizontal bar with a zigzag. I knew it was wrong, but in lecture notes with a biro it's fast to write and what does anyone care? I never taught so I never had to fix my handwriting, and I *never* willingly used both letters in the same problem solution :-)

Comment: @asmeurer: that those letters are in fact the same is another thing you need somebody to teach you. Think of the poor student having to prove that if θ = 2, then 2 * ϑ = 4.

Comment: @SteveJessop: That *is* a perfectly valid way to write $\xi$, and IMO much preferable to the all too common "corkscrew" style. Personally, I found it *much* easier to write lowercase $\xi$ and $\zeta$ clearly once I realized that they're basically just "sloppy" versions of the capital $\Xi$ and $Ζ$, which themselves are just two and three stacked horizontal lines, each with more or less optional connecting diagonals where the writer was too lazy to lift the pen.

Comment: Ps. Trivia: the [Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) $2$ and $3$ have a similar origin, which is why $2$ and $z$ (the direct descendant of $\zeta$ / $Ζ$) can be so hard to tell apart in some people's handwriting, and why $\xi$ in some fonts looks a lot like a reversed $3$ (as does $\varepsilon$, which also has a similar origin as a sloppy $Ε$).

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of tools in the mathematical toolbox that are left to incidental learning. The Greek alphabet is merely one of these, and it's a relatively unimportant one. Ideally all of these tools would be presented formally, according to a smooth learning curve, to enable future students to make faster progress than their predecessors and thus achieve greater heights, but this would be a massive undertaking and it would require an unprecedented rearrangement of mainstream educational ideas.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you should, frequently even professors mix them up. I had a professor calling eta, "nu." It was one of those drink from the fire-hose courses. I made up a flashcard with the entire Greek alphabet on it, [based on the Wikipedia table on all the letter entries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma). It was quite helpful in keeping me straight.

```
    Greek alphabet
Αα  Alpha       Νν  Nu
Ββ  Beta        Ξξ  Xi
Γγ  Gamma       Οο  Omicron
Δδ  Delta       Ππ  Pi
Εε  Epsilon     Ρρ  Rho
Ζζ  Zeta        Σσς Sigma
Ηη  Eta         Ττ  Tau
Θθ  Theta       Υυ  Upsilon
Ιι  Iota        Φφ  Phi
Κκ  Kappa       Χχ  Chi
Λλ  Lambda      Ψψ  Psi
Μμ  Mu          Ωω  Omega
```

It's important to make sure students and professors are speaking the same language. For any course that seems to run out of greek letters for symbols, you all need to know all of them.

Comment: Actually Μμ is pronounced exactly like the common word "me"  and Νν exactly like the beggining of the word (ni)rvana.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas Would do you think about the pronunciation given here, http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mu#Pronunciation ?

Comment: I am Greek.Trust me the above pronunciation I gave you is the correct-greek one.Maybe the one that is commonly used "mu" is what fits best in English pronunciation.

Comment: @Konstantinos Gaitanas: thanks! One thing that we often miss in mathematics is the native pronunciation of the letters; the English pronunciations are almost a matter of convention unrelated to the actual Greek language.

Comment: English pronunciation doesn't match modern Greek pronunciation for $\beta$, $\mu$, and $\nu$, but that doesn't make the way letters are pronounced in English "wrong" any more than the English pronunciation of Paris is "wrong" since it's not how the French say Paris.

Comment: Once when teaching abstract algebra I had a student call $\theta$ "phi", so I taught the students 3 lower-case letters a day in alphabetical order over a few weeks. I offered extra credit if a student could write the letters for me in order while naming them, and for the Greek student her task was to use English pronunciation.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas I'm curious, do you know that the modern Greek pronunciation of these letters is the same as various ancient Greek pronunciations?

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas: I think you happen to be wrong, since we use ancient Greek, so μ is actually μῦ, pronounced like [mŷː], (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C) and both "moo" and "me" are only approximations. The diphthong of "new" is still wrong, but closer.
But then, English messes up most vowels anyway. The ancient Eta was pronounced like the 'e' in bed, but both English and modern Greek change the pronunciation to [i], like the vowel in meet (but shortened).

Comment: @alex.jordan what do you mean "the modern Greek pronunciation"?I live in Greece and I have never heard the letter "μ" as "mu"

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas Oh, that's not what I meant. I'm sure that no variant of Greek ever pronounced $\mu$ as "myoo", but I am wondering if even the modern Greek pronunciation is not quite the intended way to pronounce that $\upsilon$ in $\mu\upsilon$. The vowels $\eta$, $\iota$, and $\upsilon$ are all similar sounding to my ears in modern Greek (although I don't doubt that to a native speaker there is a difference) but I always thought that "originally" they had more audible differences. I've thought the same was true for $\omicron$ and $\omega$, and with $\epsilon$ and $\alpha\iota$.

Comment: @alex.jordan yes you are totally correct,originally there was a difference between $ο$ and $ω$ , $ε$ and $αι$ and $η$ and $ι$.(And many others).

Answer (score 3):

To me, the Greek alphabet is just another character set we use.  (For a non-Greek example, the Hebrew letter *aleph*, $\aleph$, is used in discussions of cardinal numbers.)

I feel that it is a waste of time to "formally" cover it in a class--a student can easily "pick up" the alphabet just by using the letters in a class.  I can recognize nearly all of the Greek letters (upper and lower case) just from casual browsing of math/science sites/textbooks.  In one introductory engineering class, I was required to memorize the lowercase Greek alphabet, but I found I didn't need to from that casual browsing...  While that was being discussed, I felt a little cheated that valuable class time was being spent discussing something so trivial.

If students didn't have access to Google or some other search engine, any good dictionary or encyclopedia should have a total list of the characters along with their names.

Comment: Yes, but you feel like an ass when someone correct or tells you how to say it, and looks at you like your an idiot.

Comment: Really, if a student cannot get a list of greek letters unaided as a college student, he probably should not be a college student!

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely have appreciated a brief 10-20 minute introduction to the Greek alphabet at some point during my formal education.

That being said, I think the problem isn't students' lack of experience with Greek so much as math professors *incorrectly* referring to and mispronouncing letters from its alphabet. This happens somewhat frequently, especially for certain letters (read: `psi`, `xi`)  and can be pretty frustrating, especially when the mathematics itself isn't super clear.

It strikes me as somewhat antiquated, but I know many PhD programs still require a sort of perfunctory foreign language exam as a prerequisite for graduation (e.g. translate a paper written in another language). At least in theory, it would be great if this included a brief quiz on the Greek alphabet and how to correctly pronounce each letter.

The other benefit to this (again, in theory) is making people aware that there are more Greek letters out there than the ones most commonly used. Running out of symbols is not an excuse for using hard-to-read subscripts. This thread reminds me of the anecdote from John Hubbard's *Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms* (which includes a full table of the Greek alphabet in Chapter zero) about a mathematician who refers to all Greek letters except $\omega$ as "$\xi$," while referring to $\omega$ as "w."

Comment: Honesttly, if someone gets to starting his PhD and does not know the greek alphabet... well, probably not knowing the greek alphabet is the least of his problems.

Comment: "Correctly pronounce" is a complicated matter... Do you mean "correctly" for a native speaker of Greek, or a UK English speaker, or a US speaker, or the professor at hand, or something else?   I do think that a quiz whether the students can *write down* a sequence of letters spoken by the professor might be handy. But that is not so much about correct pronunciation as correct understanding of whatever pronunciation will be used.

Comment: I agree, pronunciation is a thorny issue. I only have experience with US English. Most of the pronunciations are unambiguous, but a few letters tend to cause problems. $\phi$ is regularly pronounced as both "ph-eye" and "pheee" and $\xi$ tends to be pronounced the same as $\psi$. I think it's best to avoid using $\xi$ "squiggle" except when its use is canonical.

Answer (score 2):

While there is a plethora of anecdotal evidence here, I think it might be useful to cite the approach of several text books I have come across.

- The book [Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms](http://matrixeditions.com/UnifiedApproach4th.html) starts off by giving an introduction to some notation and explicitly talks about the utility of learning the Greek alphabet. To paraphrase the book, learning what the symbols are and how to say them helps the reader remember the sysmbol and its importance.
- Nearly every high school level math text book (I have seen exceptions with science) introduced the letters as you go. This is so ubiquitous, and the textbooks vary by state, so I will not link to an example.
- The majority of statistics books that I have used introduce the variable along the way, but they make an effort to tell you what it is and how to say it. The book I have the most experience with, [Stats: Modeling the World](http://www.phschool.com/webcodes10/index.cfm?fuseaction=home.gotoWebCode&wcprefix=aze&wcsuffix=0641&x=0&y=0), does a good job of introducing them as the text progresses. In statistics it is more common to see Greek letters early on as they are used to distinguish things such as sample vs. population.
- The majority calculus and real analysis books assume knowledge of the Greek alphabet already. [Baby Rudin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007054235X) does not introduce anything, but considering the level of the course, it is reasonable, as the variable should have book seen in other courses. On the other hand, [Apostol's calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471000051) (an introductory text) introduces the other notations for set theory and the such, but does not touch on the Greek letters.

In general, there seems to the trend that with the increase in the level of rigor, the less attention is paid to such matters. It is therefore unreasonable to teach the full alphabet it in a class were either the students have seen the letters before (i.e. not an introductory) or where the Greek will not be used often (however, introduction should be given through the course of the class).

However, when it comes down to an introductory class, this is when the pedagogical methods differ. The Alphabet tends to not be taught in its entirety, but nearly all authors agree that  knowing how to pronounce the letters is helpful to the student.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to formally teach the Greek alphabet; we can just look up the letters as they appear in the exposition. Having said that, it is not hard for one to look up the entire Greek alphabet online these days, and one takes only a few moments to go through them all.

Comment: Consider this other question then: back then, it was the early 2000s and we did not even have the Internet. Maybe you could tweak your answer to "assume" the student does not have Google or what not. (:

Comment: @bryansis2010 But then you're trying to "fix" some issue that doesn't even have any bearing now. Hypotheticals like that are a bit silly.

Comment: @bryansis2010 Who is this "we" who didn't have the internet in the early 2000s?

Comment: My family didn't get dial-up until around 2005 :-(

Comment: well, i used the internet briefly in 8th grade but did not know how to use tools like google...back then we had Yahoo search only.

Comment: @bryansis2010 Good times. Good times. I remember thinking "Google" was a really great name for a search engine, since I knew the original meaning of the word, and I also remember being impressed with their clean layout. I also remember elementary-school computers with little laminated sheets on top that you were supposed to put down over the screen if you ran into anything naughty, after which you would just raise your hand and wait for an adult to come save you from the depravity.

Comment: @bryansis2010, I learned the greek letters from books. The lack of internet in my youth was not exactly a problem in that respect.

Answer (score 1):

Until the end of the last century mathematical texts written in German often used horrible Gothic letters  besides Greek letters, e.g. lowercase for vectors, uppercase for vector fields

$$\mathfrak{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$$
$$\mathfrak{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$$

Comment: This is also true of some texts written in English during the 20th century. For instance, it makes Turing's original paper in which he describes the so-called "Turing machine" a bit hard to decipher.

Comment: When you say "last century", do you mean the 20th? This style of letter is still used in various areas.

Comment: @Carl Mummert: t was talking about the 20th century. I have the impression that this alphabet is not used often today ( I would have some explanation for this). But maybe my observation is wrong.

Comment: And now imagine a written form of these instead the readable printed one, used on a blackboard. (I had a professor who liked to use these for vectors and ideals, in the starting years of the 21th century.)

Comment: When I was in HIgh school in around 2004, this style was still used in an old math-books from the early 80's. This confused us quite badly...

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! I was wondering the same thing a couple of days ago. You didn't mention the first Greek character you encountered in your life: $\pi$. Did it scare you?

Since I am teaching Calculus in high school in Eastern Asia, I am trying to avoid culturally-oriented notations which may exclude some students. For example, $\mathscr C$ (used a lot in France to denote curves) is banned for my classes since my students are not used to script characters. When explaining that the variable $x$ in the notation $f(x)=x^2$ is just a placeholder and can be substituted by anything, I include examples in their own alphabet besides the classical $f(\square)=\square^2$. I also wish to include more local history of mathematics, to go with the usual "The Ancient Greeks did not know that...". To sum up, you have to adjust to the cultural and educational background of your students.

However, when it comes to Greek alphabet, it is so widely used, together with the Latin alphabet, that students cannot afford not to know it. But the rhythm of introduction of Greek characters in maths or physics is very slow, so formally teaching it seems to me quite useless. The time between teaching $\kappa$ or $\xi$ and using it is very large and these characters will most likely be forgotten in between.

Answer (score 1):

While a few Greek letters are introduced in basic algebra and geometry, pre-calculus is the first class in which they start to gain frequency.  I claim this only because I am currently enrolled *in* the course, and being a primary source, I can ensure that my opinion is one of the community's to which this question pertains.

I believe that I am not alone when I say that Greek letters ward me away.  I think the problem isn't that students don't know the alphabet; I think the problem is that they don't know the *connotations* of the letters in mathematical context (i.e. ω is angular speed).

Compounding that issue though, is the fact that in being less familiar with a symbol, you are less likely to remember what it means.  So in that regard, I advocate the teaching of the Greek language with one caveat — you *must* explain the symbols' mathematical meanings.